# Prolog not finding all solutions

Tags: prolog

Modelling the stops of an underground tube line like so:

```
stop(line1, 1, station1).
stop(line1, 2, station2).
stop(line1, 3, station3).
stop(line1, 4, station4).
stop(line1, 5, station5).
stop(line2, 1, station2).
stop(line2, 2, station4).
```

where `stop(L, N, S)` means `S` is the `N`'th stop on line `L`, I'm trying to define `path(S1, S2, P)` that calculates possible paths between `S1` and `S2`.

Here a path is a list of "segments", a segment being a journey along the same line, i.e. `segment(L,S1,S2)` represents the continuous journey from `S1` to `S2` along line `L`. So a possible solution to `path(a,d,P)` is `P=[segment(line1, a, b), segment(line2, b, d)]`, i.e. go from `a` to `b` on `line1`, then go from `b` to `d` on `line2`.

An additional constraint is that a path should not include the same line more than once.

I've got the following:

```
segment(L, S1, S2) :- stop(L, N1, S1), stop(L, N2, S2), N2>N1.
line_present_in_path(_, []) :- false.
line_present_in_path(L, [H|_]) :- segment(L, _, _) = H.
line_present_in_path(L, [_|T]) :- line_present_in_path(L, T).
path(S1, S2, [H]) :- segment(_, S1, S2) = H, H.
path(S1, S2, [H|T]) :- segment(L, S1, X) = H, H, \+line_present_in_path(L, T), path(X, S2, T).
```

but something peculiar happens. If I explicitly specify all the parameters myself, it recognises it as a correct path:

```
?- path(station1, station4, [segment(line1, station1, station2),segment(line2, station2, station4)]).
true ;
false.
```

However, if I ask it to calculate all paths, it only finds one path, different to the path it just verified as correct:

```
?- path(station1, station4, P).
P = [segment(line1, station1, station4)] ;
false.
```

I must admit I'm new to Prolog so I might be missing something basic. But, I really can't understand why it can verify a given path as correct, but it doesn't find that path when trying to find all paths.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in the second clause for the `path/3` predicate. Rewriting it for clarity:

```
path(S1, S2, [segment(L, S1, X)|T]) :-
    \+ line_present_in_path(L, T),
    path(X, S2, T).
```

With a goal such as `path(station1, station4, P)`, you call the `line_present_in_path/2` predicate with a variable in the second argument. That call always succeeds and thus its negation always fails. In general, you should be cautious of only using `\+/1` with a sufficiently instantiated argument.

Hint: to solve the bug, use an additional argument to the path predicate to hold the stations found so far. E.g.

```
path(S1, S2, Path) :-
    path(S1, S2, Path, []).

path(S1, S2, Path, Visited) :-
    ...
```

You can use the de facto standard `member/2` predicate to check if a station is already in the path and add it to the visited list otherwise. Path finding is a common question and you will find several related answers here in StackOverflow. But try first to solve it on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand why mine is failing now but regretfully I've been staring and thinking for hours now and still can't heed your advice. Could you please expand a bit? Should I do away with `line_present_in_path` entirely or does your solution complement that?

Comment: Expanded the answer a bit as you asked.